# Materialize modal gets displayed wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

For some reason my materialize modal has a really strange layout.
I didn't touch my CSS file or changed the basic style at all. Maybe someone knows what's the problem.

My modal is not inside some div's. It's just inside the body

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();
  $('#modal1').on('click', function() {});
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../img/kristallwelt.jpg");
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Result:**
[image: Expected result]

**My Result:**
[image: My Result]

**EDIT**

After i got a solution, I'm struggling with the references. As soon as i click the button, I get this:

**Error**
[image]

In this case I have some false references.
Does someone see a problem here ?

**Including at the header**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQuery UI -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Font aswesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Materialize Logos -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Include CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
  </head>
</html>
```

**Including at the end of the body **

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css">

 <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Also this console error could be relevant

**Error**

[image]

Comment: do u have jsfiddle ? would be easy to fix.

Comment: @Princesodhi Sorry, got it now. The green round button on the green div should open div...  https://jsfiddle.net/s2y272s3/#&togetherjs=Rf4mTbkNap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a lot of thing in your HTML so I have updated your code.

**DEMO** 
https://jsfiddle.net/98w7ro4u/

**HTML**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal fade  modal-fixed-footer" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">        
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
         <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Disgree</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal1').modal('show');  
});
```

**CSS**

```
 You can use yours
```

Comment: I think I have an other problem. Could you please have a look at my edit ? I think it will be a stupid fault...

Comment: first of all, remove jQuery it is include 2 times

Comment: do u have it somewhere live?

Comment: Oh, yes. I removed it. I only got it there. Still doesn't work. Same error

Comment: Ooh, misunderstood your question. Give me a second

Comment: Got it ! https://jsfiddle.net/s2y272s3/#&togetherjs=Rf4mTbkNap The green  round button on the green div should open the modal...